# Is the set of positive real numbers a ring under these operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $L$ be the set of positive real numbers. Two operations are defined:
$$ a \oplus b = ab$$
$$a \times b = a^{\log b}.$$

Is L a ring?

1) a $\oplus$ b = ab, ab $\in$ L.
2) a x b = $ a^{\log b},  a^{\log b} \in L$.
3) addition is commutative
4)1 is the additive identity element
5) associative multiplication
6)Distributive laws
7) Associative multiplication.

8) **Is 1 the additive inverse?**

Comment: Remember that "zero" means the identity relative to $\oplus$ in this context.  It will obviously not be the usual $0$ as a real number.  Is there a positive real number $x$ such that $ax=a$ for all positive real numbers $a$?  Did you try checking all of the other properties?

Comment: I assumed that it had to be $a^{\log b}$, since $a \log b \not\in L$ when $0<b<1$…

Comment: @Aeolian: Yes, and it makes more sense in other ways.  Thanks.

Comment: I mean $a^{\log b}$.So the set of positive real numbers under normal addition and multiplication would not be a ring right? Because there is no additive identity?

Comment: @grayQuant: That is true.  Even if you took nonnegative real numbers (i.e., including $0$) it would not be a ring because of lack of additive inverses.

Comment: Wow I feel very ignorant but thanks!

Comment: The problem you forsee doesn't exist: the neutral additive element is $\,1\,$. What about the other ring axioms? Is $\,L\,$ an abelian group under that sum? Do we have associativity, distributivity (double sided in case multiplication isn't commutative)...?

Answer (score 5):

You might apply the fact that if $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism (so respecting the addition and multiplication) from a ring $R$ to a set, then its image $\phi(R)$ is again a ring.
 Now let $\phi$ be the map from the normal ring of reals $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with your addition $\oplus$ and multiplication $\otimes$, defined by $\phi(a)=e^{a}$, where $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm. Obviously this is a well-defined bijection. One can easily check that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism. Observe that 0 is mapped to 1 (the neutral element w.r.t. $\oplus$), and the unit 1 is mapped to $e$ (the neutral element w.r.t. $\otimes$). Hence, the two rings are even isomorphic!

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> > Is there a zero element in the set of positive real numbers?

What this means in this context is:

> > Is there a positive real number $a$ such that $a\oplus x=x$ for all positive real numbers $x$?

The defintion of $a\oplus x$ is $ax$, where the latter is ordinary multiplication.  Is there a positive real number $a$ such that $ax=x$ for all positive real numbers $x$?

You write:

> > I see that L is a ring with the given properties but...

I don't see how you can see it is a ring if you don't know whether there is an additive identity.  I suggest checking every single one of the properties of a ring to verify whether or not it holds.  You can ask for more specific help if you get stuck on any other parts.

Comment: The additive identity is 1, clear to me now.

Comment: @grayQuant: So what's left?  Have you checked whether every property from the definition of ring holds?

Comment: Is 1 the additive inverse? Because a $\oplus$ 1 = 1.

Comment: @grayQuant: No.  Firstly, $a\oplus 1=a$ for all $a$, not $1$.  Secondly, there are different additive inverses for different elements (provided they exist).  For that property, you want to check, for an arbitrary but fixed $a$, can you find an element $b$ such that $a\oplus b=1$ (now that you know that $1$ is "zero").  Again, use the definition of $\oplus$ to simplify the problem of finding $b$.

Comment: I think it is 1/a.

Comment: @grayQuant: That is right.

Comment: I am having trouble showing a(bc) = (ab)c.                **a x bc = $a^{log bc}$. ab x c = $ab^{logc}$**

Comment: @grayQuant: Please be careful with notation and think about how the associative property should be written here.  It would be $a\times(b\times c)=(a\times b)\times c$.  That is not what you have; you seem to have gotten some of the "multiplications" mixed up with ordinary multiplications.  For example, $2\times (3\times 4)=2\times (3^{\log 4})=2^{\log(3^{\log 4})}$.